# json fail in django ('tuple' object has no attribute '_meta')

Tags: python, json, django

my view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_order_detail(request):
    order_id = request.GET['order_id']
    products_of_order = OrdersProducts.objects.filter(order=order_id).values('product__title', 'cargo_no', 'order',
                                                                         'units', "status").values_list()
    data = serializers.serialize("json", products_of_order)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="text/json", safe=False)
```

my model:

```
class OrdersProducts(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (u'0', _(u'cancel')),
        (u'1', _(u'waiting_for_payment')),
        (u'2', _(u'waiting_for_cargo')),
        (u'3', _(u'on_the_road')),
        (u'4', _(u'success_shipping')),
        (u'5', _(u'failure_shipping')),
        (u'6', _(u'return'))
    )
    units = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, null=False, blank=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='1')
    cargo_no = models.CharField(max_length=11, default='', null=True, blank=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Orders)
    optional_price = models.ForeignKey(OptionalPrice, default=1)
    company_optional_price = models.ForeignKey(CompanyOptionalPrice, default=1)
    cdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my template:

```
$('.order-btn').click(function(event) {
        var order = $(this).data('id');
        var items = [];
        $('#table_order').find('tbody').empty();
        if ( order != "" ) {
            items.push ('');
            $.getJSON ( '{% url 'get_order_detail' %}', {order_id:order}, function(data) {
                console.log('sa');
                $.each ( data, function ( index, val ) {
                    console.log(data);
                    items.push ( '<tr><td>' + val.fields.order + '</td> <td>' + val.fields.product_name + '</td> <td>' + val.fields.units + '</td> <td>' + val.fields.optional_price + '</td> <td>' + val.fields.get_status_display + '</td>  <td>' + val.fields.cargo_no + '</td></tr>');
                    console.log(items)
                } );
                $('#table_order').find('tbody').append( items );
            } );
        }
    });
```

error:

> tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

I need a values('product__title', 'cargo_no', 'order', 'units', "status").  If I can my mymodel.objects.all(), don't use product.name values,etc.
Note: My template page is old values when I use to direct my model.

Comment: Please, provide the full traceback. What version of Django are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing Django queryset to JSON: getting AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute '\_meta'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629532/serializing-django-queryset-to-json-getting-attributeerror-tuple-object-has-n)

Comment: I use Django 1.6.1 and method don't work on link